# How to effectivelly attach value to references table id?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, enums

I have a table "products" for my website. There is the product_id, image and bunch of information like manufacturer, health, age etc. When I started to work on my projekts I chose to save everything as ENUMs like this:

```
manufacturer ENUM('manufacturer1', 'manufacturer2', 'manufacturer3', 'manufacturer4'),
```

However dealing with more stuff I have realized that this is not the best approach for me. So I decided to create reference tables. For manufacturer it looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE manufacturer(
    manufacturer_id  INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (manufacturer_id  ),
    UNIQUE INDEX name (name)
);
```

but in products table I now have:

```
manufacturer_id INT(10),
```

The question is on what is the best way to assign value from reference table. I am using CI framework and it was very easy to display product in view. However now when I run query for product I get "3" instead of "manufacturer3".

I could use JOIN but I would have 7 JOINs. I created library with function that ataches the value. But I have to save all the possible values in that function or to query every reference table every time I use library.

I mean there are a lot of articles about why not to use ENUMs and I get that - I run in problems with ENUM in my project myself. I dont get how to convert those reference ids to real value (efectivelly, I dont think that 7 JOINs is a good way to that especially if I have to do that very often)

Comment: Could you please add your SQL query? Is the field "manufacturer" still in the "products" table after the DataBase normalization?